# Calabash IOS Unable to find xcode project

Tags: calabash-ios

Hi guys any one knows how to resolve this problem on calabash I tried to run my first scenario but I getting an error, it's my first time to use Calabash and i'm not really a developer I'm only a QA tester I don't have any idea how to fix this problem can you show me or steps to fix this?

```
**Scenario: Example steps**        
                    # features/my_first.feature:6
  Unable to find *.xcodeproj in /Users/FDMCarlo (RuntimeError)
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.16.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/launch/simulator_launcher.rb:106:in `derived_data_dir_for_project'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.16.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/launch/simulator_launcher.rb:223:in `app_bundle_or_raise'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.16.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:573:in `relaunch'
  /Users/FDMCarlo/features/support/01_launch.rb:27:in `Before'
    Given I am on the Welcome Screen                 # features/step_definitions/my_first_steps.rb:1
    Then I swipe left                                # calabash-cucumber-0.16.3/features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb:222
    And I wait until I don't see "Please swipe left" # calabash-cucumber-0.16.3/features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb:158
    And take picture                                 # calabash-cucumber-0.16.3/features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb:217

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/my_first.feature:6 # Scenario: Example steps
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `APP` command line variable to point to your application.  This is assuming you are testing against a simulator.

```
$ APP=/path/to/your.app cucumber
```

If you are testing against devices, please see this guide on the [Calabash iOS wiki](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Testing-on-Physical-Devices).

Please update your answer with the *exact* command you are trying to run.

When reporting problems, please see this [wiki page](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki#reporting-problems) which shows the details we need to answer your questions correctly.

Comment: HI Sir jmoody can you show me how to run the $ APP=/path/to/your.app cucumber or how to point my application to the simulator because I dont have any idea about it  Thanks :)

Comment: This repo https://github.com/calabash/ios-smoke-test-app has examples of how to stage apps and ipas to local directories when building from the command line and Xcode.